# I've changed position of vertices with python but nothing happened

Tags: python, mesh, scripting

I'm really newbie at blender. So I want to change an object from a python script.

If I create a new project (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>) and open python console, I can changing position of vertices:

```
bpy.data.meshes['Cube'].vertices[0].co.z += 20
```

But if I'm using .blend file with mesh from here:
http://www.blender-models.com/model-downloads/humans/id/head-mesh/
I can changing vertices too

but I don't see anything new at 3D view window.
[image]

What I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try your statements with the 3D View Window in object mode not edit mode.

[image]

Comment: An explanation of *why* this needs to be done might be helpful.

Comment: You might add that in the comments

Comment: Well, you obviously know why otherwise why would you suggest them to do that? I'm just suggesting to flesh the answer out a bit.

Comment: I do [not] know why everything happens in Blender at the software text level because I read approximately 00.00 % of the software text by choice. I may have a good educated theory.  I answered to get him one step further.  It is always a question of whether to write for the poser or some unknown readers.  I estimate there will be few readers. Thus the short answer.  Perhaps I want to hear your explanation.